# Creating new levels

Tags: java, game-development

As a beginner in Java, I'm working on a project of Space Invaders. Looking to add more levels.

```
private void LevelInit() {
    aliens = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentLevel = 1;

        if (currentLevel == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                    var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j, Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
                    aliens.add(alien);
                    //System.out.println(currentLevel);


                }

            }
        }
        else if (currentLevel == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                    var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j, Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
                    aliens.add(alien);

                   // System.out.println(currentLevel);


                }
            }
        }
        else if (currentLevel == 3) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

                    var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j, Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
                    aliens.add(alien);
                    //System.out.println(currentLevel);
                }

            }
        }
        




    player = new Player();
    bullet = new Bullet();


}
```

This function is the logic behind the code that initializes the game and gets called by the constructor. The simple way of adding levels is adding more Aliens.
This is how it looks after being updated from yesterday, levels are being added but the arraylists are being stuck together. Like the 12 - 16 - 24 aliens are together printed, some spaceships take 1 hit some 2 and some 3 and when they are all destroyed system give message of You passed level 1 and 2 and 3 together which is confusing me why are they bound together like that and not being passed.
And I can't figure it out. Also,

```
    private void update() {

    if (deaths == 12) {

            inGame = false;
            timer.stop();
            message = "Next Level!";

    }
    // player
    player.act();

    // shot
    if (bullet.isVisible()) {

        int shotX = bullet.getX();
        int shotY = bullet.getY();

        for (Alien alien : aliens) {

            int alienX = alien.getX();
            int alienY = alien.getY();

            if (alien.isVisible() && bullet.isVisible()) {
                if (shotX >= (alienX)
                        && shotX <= (alienX + Constants.ALIEN_WIDTH)
                        && shotY >= (alienY)
                        && shotY <= (alienY + Constants.ALIEN_HEIGHT)) {

                    var ii = new ImageIcon(explImg);
                    alien.setImage(ii.getImage());
                    alien.setDying(true);
                    deaths++;
                    bullet.die();
                }
            }
        }

        int y = bullet.getY();
        y -= 4;

        if (y < 0) {
            bullet.die();
        } else {
            bullet.setY(y);
        }
    }

    // aliens

    for (Alien alien : aliens) {

        int x = alien.getX();

        if (x >= Constants.BOARD_WIDTH - Constants.BORDER_RIGHT && direction != -1) {

            direction = -1;

            for(Alien a2 : aliens) {
                a2.setY(a2.getY() + Constants.GO_DOWN);
            }
        }

        if (x <= Constants.BORDER_LEFT && direction != 1) {

            direction = 1;


            for(Alien a : aliens) {

                a.setY(a.getY() + Constants.GO_DOWN);
            }
        }
    }



    for(Alien alien : aliens) {


        if (alien.isVisible()) {

            int y = alien.getY();

            if (y > Constants.GROUND - Constants.ALIEN_HEIGHT) {
                inGame = false;
                message = "Invasion!";
            }

            alien.act(direction);
        }
    }

    // bombs
    var generator = new Random();

    for (Alien alien : aliens) {

        int shot = generator.nextInt(15);
        Alien.Bomb bomb = alien.getBomb();

        if (shot == Constants.CHANCE && alien.isVisible() && bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            bomb.setDestroyed(false);
            bomb.setX(alien.getX());
            bomb.setY(alien.getY());
        }

        int bombX = bomb.getX();
        int bombY = bomb.getY();
        int playerX = player.getX();
        int playerY = player.getY();

        if (player.isVisible() && !bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            if (bombX >= (playerX)
                    && bombX <= (playerX + Constants.PLAYER_WIDTH)
                    && bombY >= (playerY)
                    && bombY <= (playerY + Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT)) {

                var ii = new ImageIcon(explImg);
                player.setImage(ii.getImage());
                player.setDying(true);
                bomb.setDestroyed(true);
            }
        }

        if (!bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            bomb.setY(bomb.getY() + 1);

            if (bomb.getY() >= Constants.GROUND - Constants.BOMB_HEIGHT) {

                bomb.setDestroyed(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is to update the game whenever anything happens. The code is made from a bunch of YouTube videos and GitHubs, so excuse the copying if you see any.
I need to create new levels by simply adding more aliens, tried using a for loop but that resulted in either the aliens move faster or the bullet doesn't destroy an alien, it just hits.

Board class:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

private Dimension d;
private List<Alien> aliens;
private Player player;
private Bullet bullet;
private int level;
private int direction = -1;
private int deaths = 0;

private boolean inGame = true;
private String explImg = "src/images/explosion.png";
private String message = "Game Over";

private Timer timer;


public Board() {


    initBoard();
    gameInit();
    LevelInit();


}

private void initBoard() {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    d = new Dimension(Constants.BOARD_WIDTH, Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.black);

    timer = new Timer(Constants.DELAY, new GameCycle());
    timer.start();

    gameInit();

}


private void gameInit() {

    aliens = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j,
                    Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
            aliens.add(alien);

        }
    }


    player = new Player();
    bullet = new Bullet();

}
private void LevelInit() {


    inGame = true;
    timer.start();
    int level = 1;
    if (aliens.isEmpty()) {
        level++;
        int AlienCount;if(level == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j, Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
                    aliens.add(alien);

                }
            }
        } else if (level == 3) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    var alien = new Alien(Constants.ALIEN_INIT_X + 18 * j, Constants.ALIEN_INIT_Y + 18 * i);
                    aliens.add(alien);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    player = new Player();
    bullet = new Bullet();
}





private void drawAliens(Graphics g) {

    for (Alien alien : aliens) {

        if (alien.isVisible()) {

            g.drawImage(alien.getImage(), alien.getX(), alien.getY(), this);
        }

        if (alien.isDying()) {

            alien.die();
        }
    }
}

private void drawPlayer(Graphics g) {

    if (player.isVisible()) {

        g.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);
    }

    if (player.isDying()) {

        player.die();
        inGame = false;
    }
}

private void drawShot(Graphics g) {

    if (bullet.isVisible()) {

        g.drawImage(bullet.getImage(), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), this);
    }
}

private void drawBombing(Graphics g) {

    for (Alien a : aliens) {

        Alien.Bomb b = a.getBomb();

        if (!b.isDestroyed()) {

            g.drawImage(b.getImage(), b.getX(), b.getY(), this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    doDrawing(g);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    g.setColor(Color.green);

    if (inGame) {

        g.drawLine(0, Constants.GROUND,
                Constants.BOARD_WIDTH, Constants.GROUND);

        drawAliens(g);
        drawPlayer(g);
        drawShot(g);
        drawBombing(g);

    } else {

        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
        }

        gameOver(g);
    }

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void gameOver(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.BOARD_WIDTH, Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(new Color(0, 32, 48));
    g.fillRect(50, Constants.BOARD_WIDTH / 2 - 30, Constants.BOARD_WIDTH - 100, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawRect(50, Constants.BOARD_WIDTH / 2 - 30, Constants.BOARD_WIDTH - 100, 50);

    var small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    var fontMetrics = this.getFontMetrics(small);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(small);
    g.drawString(message, (Constants.BOARD_WIDTH - fontMetrics.stringWidth(message)) / 2,
            Constants.BOARD_WIDTH / 2);
}

private void update() {

    if (deaths == aliens.size()) {

            inGame = false;
            timer.stop();
            message = "Next Level!";


    }
    // player
    player.act();

    // shot
    if (bullet.isVisible()) {

        int shotX = bullet.getX();
        int shotY = bullet.getY();

        for (Alien alien : aliens) {

            int alienX = alien.getX();
            int alienY = alien.getY();

            if (alien.isVisible() && bullet.isVisible()) {
                if (shotX >= (alienX)
                        && shotX <= (alienX + Constants.ALIEN_WIDTH)
                        && shotY >= (alienY)
                        && shotY <= (alienY + Constants.ALIEN_HEIGHT)) {

                    var ii = new ImageIcon(explImg);
                    alien.setImage(ii.getImage());
                    alien.setDying(true);
                    deaths++;
                    bullet.die();
                }
            }
        }

        int y = bullet.getY();
        y -= 4;

        if (y < 0) {
            bullet.die();
        } else {
            bullet.setY(y);
        }
    }

    // aliens

    for (Alien alien : aliens) {

        int x = alien.getX();

        if (x >= Constants.BOARD_WIDTH - Constants.BORDER_RIGHT && direction != -1) {

            direction = -1;

            Iterator<Alien> i1 = aliens.iterator();

            while (i1.hasNext()) {

                Alien a2 = i1.next();
                a2.setY(a2.getY() + Constants.GO_DOWN);
            }
        }

        if (x <= Constants.BORDER_LEFT && direction != 1) {

            direction = 1;

            Iterator<Alien> i2 = aliens.iterator();

            while (i2.hasNext()) {

                Alien a = i2.next();
                a.setY(a.getY() + Constants.GO_DOWN);
            }
        }
    }

    Iterator<Alien> it = aliens.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Alien alien = it.next();

        if (alien.isVisible()) {

            int y = alien.getY();

            if (y > Constants.GROUND - Constants.ALIEN_HEIGHT) {
                inGame = false;
                message = "Invasion!";
            }

            alien.act(direction);
        }
    }

    // bombs
    var generator = new Random();

    for (Alien alien : aliens) {

        int shot = generator.nextInt(15);
        Alien.Bomb bomb = alien.getBomb();

        if (shot == Constants.CHANCE && alien.isVisible() && bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            bomb.setDestroyed(false);
            bomb.setX(alien.getX());
            bomb.setY(alien.getY());
        }

        int bombX = bomb.getX();
        int bombY = bomb.getY();
        int playerX = player.getX();
        int playerY = player.getY();

        if (player.isVisible() && !bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            if (bombX >= (playerX)
                    && bombX <= (playerX + Constants.PLAYER_WIDTH)
                    && bombY >= (playerY)
                    && bombY <= (playerY + Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT)) {

                var ii = new ImageIcon(explImg);
                player.setImage(ii.getImage());
                player.setDying(true);
                bomb.setDestroyed(true);
            }
        }

        if (!bomb.isDestroyed()) {

            bomb.setY(bomb.getY() + 1);

            if (bomb.getY() >= Constants.GROUND - Constants.BOMB_HEIGHT) {

                bomb.setDestroyed(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void doGameCycle() {

    update();
    repaint();
}

private class GameCycle implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        doGameCycle();
    }
}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        player.keyReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        player.keyPressed(e);

        int x = player.getX();
        int y = player.getY();

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

            if (inGame) {

                if (!bullet.isVisible()) {

                    bullet = new Bullet(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think it will be better if you use a function similar to `gameInit()`. It will be something like `levelInit(int alienCount)`. Any changes made in the `update()` will mostly result in changes during the current level. *It is best to keep initialization and updation separate*.

Comment: I don't see where you have tried to create a new level or [adding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) new Aliens in your code?

Comment: @Quadslab I deleted the function because they had errors, and failed to compile. So I am asking for advice right now.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I don't know what `inGame` is used for, nor what `timer` is, or what `message` is used for. I can assume that you want to add the aliens after `message = "Next Level!";`, but I can't know for sure by the code you have given.

Comment: @Quadslab Edited post added Board Class and I did as -AKSingh said, and tried adding a levelInit function but it's not adding aliens, just moving to next level, maybe I placed it in a wrong place? I don't really know..

Comment: @KareemRj: what you're experiencing right now is the need to refactor: refactoring is changing the structure of the code without affecting what it does. If you can separate the initialization of the game into a dedicated method, then changing it to have multiple levels becomes easier, because you only have to modify code related to that method and not touch the other stuff which is logically independent but might not yet be strictly separated enough to actually be independent.

Comment: Good question, what you can do is take in an `int level` in the constructor, and according to that generate the aliens, `if(Math.random() < level/100f)spawnNewAlien() // this will have a level/100th of chance to generate a alien`, please reply if I did not understand your question

Comment: @pickypotato nice name lol. And I think you misunderstood, I need to add new levels, like first level its 12 aliens, next is 18, and last is 25, but you gave me an idea to add powerups! Thanks!

Comment: @KareemRj, one thing that you can do is take an `int numberOfAliens` in the constructor of the game and, then `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAliens; i++)alienArrayList.add(new Alien())`, please tell me if I understood you correctly or I misunderstood again.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new `Level` class that contains the number of enemies. It also has a `List` of all enemies and you access enemies only through the `Level` class. You could add an update and draw methld to the class, im which you iterate over the enemies. You create the enemy-list in the constructor of `Level` and then it's basically as simple as saying `currentLevel=new Level(20)` for creating a Level with 20 enemies.

Comment: Will there be any changes to the `player` in the next level?

Comment: @AKSingh no, just adding more aliens, then I want to add a function that randomly drops a powerup if alien is destroyed, those powerups however will affect the player.

Comment: @KareemRj In the next level, the power up from previous level should be there?

Comment: @AKSingh well no, if you passed the level with a power up it shouldn't still be there, should be removed and start the level normally, But if you mean a power up hasn't been picked up and player passed the level, then also no the board should be cleared before entering another level,

Comment: And can a switch case be used for implementing levels? I changed gameInit() function with levelInit() with a switch case of levels.

Answer (score 1):

As @JoachimSauer mentioned, your code needs refactoring. Here is one possible solution to your problem.

---

### Additions

You will need two extra variables and one extra method.

- *Variables*

  ```
  1: int currentLevel - keeps track of the current level
  2: boolean isLevelOver - keeps track if the current level is still active or not
  ```
- *Method*

  ```
  private void levelInit(int currentlevel)
  {
      aliens = new ArrayList<>();
      int alienCount = //calculate alien count depending upon the current level

      //Add aliens to aliens ArrayList

      player = new Player();
      bullet = new Bullet();
  }
  ```

You have to provide implementation of how `alienCount` will be calculated *depending* upon `currentLevel`. The nested loop you used earlier to add aliens to `aliens` will also change. You have to make the loop *dependent* upon `currentLevel`.

---

### Changes

Few of your methods will require some change.

```
public Board() 
{
    initBoard();
}

private void initBoard()
{
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    d = new Dimension(Constants.BOARD_WIDTH, Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.black);

    levelInit(currentLevel);

    timer = new Timer(Constants.DELAY, new GameCycle());
    timer.start();
}

private void update() 
{
    if (deaths == aliens.size()) 
    {
        isLevelOver = true;
        currentLevel++;
        message = "Next Level!";
        return;
    }

    ...
}

private void doGameCycle() 
{
    if (isLevelOver)
    {
        levelInit(currentLevel);
        isLevelOver = false;
    }
    
    update();
    repaint();
}
```

---

### Notes

- This is *one of the possible ways to achieve what you want*. There
  might be other ways, probably better, but this is what I came up
  with.
- *I tried to find as many additions and updation required in your code. However, I do not know its structure, you do. So there might be more additions or changes required.*
- I noticed you are were calling `gameInit()` in `initBoard()` and then again in `Board()` constructor. *I think that might be unnecessary, please look into it.*
- You made one call to `timer.stop()` after setting `isGame = false`. *This again might be unnecessary* since you are already doing so inside `doDrawing(...)`. *Please also check that.*
- You should probably *set a limit to either the `levelCount()` or max alien that can be on the screen* since if you just keep on adding more aliens in each new level, they might fill up the entire screen.

---

I have provided many hints which should help you in your problem. If you still face any more problems or someone finds anything wrong with the answer, please comment.

Comment: I did as you said, but now when the level finishes, not only  "next level" message doesn't show, but the entire application freezes.

Comment: Did you run a debugger? I will be needing more information before I can help you. I can not re-create your code in my IDE, so it will be hard to debug.

Comment: is there anyway for like a chat or anything? Maybe you can provide more help than you actually did. I can send you the entire code.

Comment: Well, it worked for passing to higher levels, but it doesn't require the player to destroy all the alien ship :D. So, new problem arises.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233461/discussion-between-aksingh-and-kareemrj).